# How do I avoid code duplication when creating message notifications for vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

On the project I am working on, we have many notification bars like this [image]

Not to generate a message I am using it this approach.

The is the HTML part:

```
<template>
  <div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" v-if="registration.isFinished">
      <button type="button" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true" class="close">×</button> 
      <h4><i class="icon fa fa-check"></i> {{ success.msg }} user "{{ field.user.name }}" created! </h4>
       <h4><i class="icon fa fa-check"></i> {{ success.desc }} user "{{ field.user.name }}" created!

      Click  <router-link to="/profile">Here</router-link> to view your new profile </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>
```

You can see I am using `registration.isFinished` to display the success message and `success.msg` and `success.desc` get shown after that.

Now this is the JS version.

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      registration : {
        isFinished: false; 
      },
      success: {
        msg: '',
        desc: ''
      }
    }
  },

  methods: {
      registerUser() {
        // if user is registered 
        this.registration.isFinished = true
        this.success.msg = 'Congratulations'
        this.success.desc = 'Your account has been created'  
      }
  }
}
```

Now, if this was just to show one message on one component, it would be fine.. but I have other notifications also, .. ex: error, info ... and for all my pages. So, I ended up with lots of duplicated content in my app.

Is there any way to minimize the code duplication? I know the answer lies somewhere in making components, but I'm not sure how that is done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You indeed need to make an "alert component".

This is how it works:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="alert alert-dismissible" :class="'alert-' + type">
            <h4>{{ title }}</h4>
            <slot></slot>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            title: {
                type: String, 
                required: false
            },
            type: {
                type: String,
                required: false,
                default: 'success'
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

And this is how you use it in an other component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <alert title="The title of my component" type="success">
            The content of my alert
        </alert>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import Alert from './Alert.vue'

    export default {
        components: {
            Alert
        }
    }
</script>
```

As you can see, the Alert component accepts two props, title and type. The type will define your alert color thanks to `:class="'alert-' + type"` in the component.

I hope you make that work

Comment: Perfect. Just two things I don't understand. What is the `<slot></slot>` for?  Every tag seems to make sense except that one. Also, is there a convention to keep components like these somewhere? like a folder?

Comment: The `<slot></slot>` tags are here to indicate that the "content" of your new created html tag will be placed here. So when I write `<alert title="The title of my component" type="success">The content of my alert</alert>`, in your alert component, `<slot></slot>` will be replaced by `The content of my alert`.

Comment: And I don't know about such conventions, try to organize as best as you can and as best as it fits to your needs